# iOS use of NSColor versus UIColor?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uicolor, nscolor

What's the difference between `UIColor` and `NSColor`, and when would one use each? I came across `NSColor` while trying to figure out `UIColor` uses for attributed strings in iOS. I understand the use of `UIColor` for the UIKit and such, but I don't think `NSColor` is really useful for this kind of thing. Has `NSColor` fallen into disuse with regards to iOS programming?

Comment: `NSColor` is an OSX class. `UIColor` is an iOS class.

Comment: Why is everybody down-voting this question? The docs don't always make it clear when they are referring to OSX vs iOS, and it's very confusing, especially to an iOS novice. I've been doing iOS and Mac OS for years, and still sometimes get confused with docs that cover both Mac OS and iOS. I think this is a legitimate question

Comment: @DuncanC Very true. Mac Docs sometimes cover iOS programming guides as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such thing as NSColor in iOS. UIColor is what you should use.

NSColor only exists as a OSX class.

Answer (score 8):

As Nate says, NSColor is OSX only. If you ran across a mention of it in the docs on NSAttributedString, it's probably documentation intended for Mac OS. Some of the docs do "bleed over" between platforms.

If you search the Xcode docs for `NSAttributedString(NSStringDrawing)` you'll see some UIKit additions to NSAttributedString that let you specify colors using UIColors.

It looks like the equivalent OS X application kit extensions are called `NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringKitAdditions)`. Gotta love the consistent naming conventions, huh?

Answer (score 4):

NSColor is from AppKit and UIColor is from UIKit. UIKit was built from the ground up for iOS and AppKit came over from NeXT. As AppKit is a Mac only framework you cannot use NSColor in an iOS app.